# Easy way to swap characters in command line with emacs key bindings?

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

If I'm in vi, and I see that I've transposed two characters, it is easily fixed by putting the cursor over the first and typing `x` followed by `p` in command mode.

Is there a similar trick that works at the bash command line in emacs mode? I realize that I can set to vi key bindings, but I prefer not to do that given that emacs key bindings are the default for many command lines in my life.

Comment: looking for ctrl-t????

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Emacs key binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> runs the command transpose-chars, which also works in the terminal

Comment: yay! same as Sublime.. easy to remember